# Query to fetch data from array_aggregate

Tags: presto

I have column with data in array.

```
Alphabets    
{A,B,C}
{A}
{B,C}
```

I need a query which gives me output as A for {A}

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY
  [
    ARRAY[1,2,3,4],
    ARRAY[5,6,7,8],
    ARRAY[9,0]
  ] AS items
),
item AS (
  SELECT i AS array_items
  FROM dataset, UNNEST(items) AS t(i)
)
SELECT array_items, sum(val) AS total
FROM item, UNNEST(array_items) AS t(val)
GROUP BY array_items;
```

In the last SELECT statement, instead of using sum() and UNNEST, you can use reduce() to decrease processing time and data transfer, as in the following example.

```
WITH
dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY
  [
    ARRAY[1,2,3,4],
    ARRAY[5,6,7,8],
    ARRAY[9,0]
  ] AS items
),
item AS (
  SELECT i AS array_items
  FROM dataset, UNNEST(items) AS t(i)
)
SELECT array_items, reduce(array_items, 0 , (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s) AS total
FROM item;
```

Either query returns the following results. The order of returned results is not guaranteed.

```
+----------------------+
| array_items  | total |
+----------------------+
| [1, 2, 3, 4] | 10    |
| [5, 6, 7, 8] | 26    |
| [9, 0]       | 9     |
+----------------------+
```

reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/arrays-and-aggregation.html